# An adverb for performing a punitive action on someone who is actually not guilty?

Tags: word-request, adverbs

What's the right adverb for describing a punitive action that is done when the one being punished is actually not guilty?

For example,

> Those who had been **___________ly** thrown into prisons and withered in them 
>   for years, were all now suddenly released.
>
> Father often gave his sons a good deal of spanking  **______________ly**,
>   which took its own tally on him when they grew up.
>
> All those cases, in which the judge had issued a capital punishment
>   ____________**ly**, weighed on him now greatly.

(I place ***ly*** in the end of each blank because adverbs usually end that way in English; however, if there is an adverb of some other form, that will be fine, too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wrongfully" would be the word I'd expect in the first sentence; possibly "erroneously", but I think wrongfully is more common for false imprisonment.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/wrongfully

Answer (score 2):

**unjustly** would work:

> characterized by injustice : [unfair](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfair)
>   // The convict received an **unjust** sentence.

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unjustly))

That doesn't really help you if you don't know what [*injustice*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/injustice) means:

> absence of justice : violation of right or of the rights of another : unfairness